# Create a custom tab for my lwc in salesforce using coding (Apex/JS/html)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tab

So i know the steps to create a custom tab in salesforce using the following instructions:

1. Create a custom tab for the component.
2. From Setup, enter Tabs in the Quick Find box, then select Tabs.
3. Click New in the Lightning Component Tabs related list.
4. Select the Lightning component that you want to make available to users.
5. Enter a label to display on the tab.
6. Select the tab style and click Next.
7. When prompted to add the tab to profiles, accept the default and click Save.
8. Your Lightning component is now available from the All Items section of the App Launcher on desktop, and the All Items navigation
   menu item in the Salesforce mobile app.

I want a way through coding using an XML file or something. Like we create custom lightning objects using coding, can we do the same for custom lightning tabs?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make your **LWC** component available as a custom tab by adding the [`lightning__Tab`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-custom-tab.html) target in the component’s configuration file **(componentName.js-meta.xml)**. You also need to set the **isExposed** attribute to true.

For example:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
<apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
<target>lightning__Tab</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Next, you need to create a custom tab for your **LWC** component using **Apex** code. You can use the **[MetadataService](https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls)** class to create and deploy metadata components, such as custom tabs, programmatically.

For example:

```
// Create an instance of the service
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();

// Create a custom tab object
MetadataService.CustomTab customTab = new MetadataService.CustomTab();
customTab.fullName = 'HelloWorld'; // The name of the custom tab
customTab.label = 'Hello World'; // The label of the custom tab
customTab.lightningComponentBundle = 'helloWorld'; // The name of the LWC component
customTab.motif = 'Custom53: Puzzle'; // The icon of the custom tab

// Create a list of metadata components to deploy
List<MetadataService.Metadata> components = new List<MetadataService.Metadata>();
components.add(customTab);

// Deploy the components using the service
MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.deployMetadata(components);
```

Finally, you need to check the deployment status and retrieve the result using the **checkDeployStatus** and **retrieve** methods of the service.

For example:

```
// Check the deployment status using the service
MetadataService.DeployResult result = service.checkDeployStatus(results[0].id, true);

// Retrieve the result using the service
MetadataService.RetrieveResult retrieveResult = service.retrieve(result.id);
```

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for responding. Can you explain how will this code be connected with my lightning web component? And do i need to make a separate class for this code?

Comment: you need to write a separate apex class for this.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't get your point. Do i need to make a separate class to connect my lightning web component with my custom tab ?

Comment: You need to import all the metadata classes from Metadata WSDL to get this working.
Run the above code into the anonymous window. Also please change the tab name and lwc component name into the code.

Comment: It looks like you are using a GPT to generate answers because Apex does not have an import statement.

Comment: Got your point. Thank you so much.